# How to shade area and make it transparent between two lines in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I shaded the area between two lines, it's not very clean:

```
area(xData,[Y1(:) ,Y2(:)-Y1(:)]); hold on

colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 1]);
```

How to make it transparent too in MATLAB? So that it comes like:

[image: graph]

ref:peltiertech.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`FaceAlpha`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/add-transparency-to-graphics-objects.html) property of the `area` object to set the transparency level:

```
xData = 1:7;
Y1 = [3 2 1 4 3 2 1];
Y2 = [8 6 9 8 7 5 6];
area(xData, Y2, 'EdgeColor',[0 .447 .741], 'FaceColor',[0.929 .694 .125], 'FaceAlpha',.3);
hold on
area(xData, Y1, 'EdgeColor',[0 .447 .741], 'FaceColor', [1 1 1]);
```

A cleaner approach is to use [`patch`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) instead of `area`:

```
h = patch([xData xData(end:-1:1) xData(1)], [Y1 Y2(end:-1:1) Y1(1)], 'b');
set(h, 'EdgeColor',[0 .447 .741], 'FaceColor',[0.929 .694 .125], 'FaceAlpha',.3)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working in R2019b version, not sure why. It does not fill the area, just creates the patch. Worked in older version though.

Comment: @Melb Weird. I just tested in R2019a (Windows) and in R2019b (Matlab Online) and both approaches work for me